# How to test a method returning a Promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, es6-promise

I'm writing an Angular 2 RC5 application, and unit testing using Karma and Jasmine.

**I have a method that returns a `Promise<Foo>`** (It's on top of a call to angular's http.post) **I want to run some assertions after that finishes.**

Something like this doesn't work

```
let result = myService.getFoo();
result.then(rslt => expect(1+1).toBe(3)); // the error is lost
```

This creates an 'Unhandled Promise rejection' warning, but the error is suppressed and the test passes. **How do I run assertions based on my resolved promise?**

Notes:

- The .catch() method doesn't seem to be what I'm after. I don't want to log or do anything that continues normal program flow, I want to fail the test.
- I've seen code that looks like `$rootScope.$digest();`. I'm not sure what the typescript equivalent of this sort of thing is. There doesn't seem to be a way of saying: "I have a promise, I'm going to wait here until I have a synchronous result".

Comment: Do you have babel (specifically babel-polyfill) in your build-stack? You should be able to use async/await to wait for the promise to be fulfilled.

Comment: Notice that Jasmine allows synchronous specs with `jasmine.clock` (an alternative to A1's `$rootScope.$digest()`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The test should look something like this:

```
it('should getFoo', function (done) {
  let result = myService.getFoo();
  result
    .then(rslt => expect(rslt).toBe('foo'))
    .then(done);
});
```

Comment: Yep, thanks. I was missing the `then(done);` (for the `DoneFn` parameter). Which meant my asserts were blowing up after the spec had finished.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `done` callback works, but you should be able to do this as well:

(Note the `return`)

```
it('should getFoo', function () {
  let result = myService.getFoo();
  return result
    .then(rslt => expect(rslt).toBe('foo'))
});
```